# Is it possible to run a mysqli query directly via the link while a statement is opened?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple operation on a MySQL database: my contacts have their complete names on a column called `first_name` while the column `last_name` is empty.

So I want to take what's on the `first_name` column and split it on the first occurrence of a white space and put the first part on the `first_name` column and the second part on the `last_name` column.

I use the following code but it's not working:

```
$connection = new mysqli(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_PORT);

$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT id, first_name FROM contacts");

$statement->execute();

$statement->bind_result($row->id, $row->firstName);

while ($statement->fetch()) {
  $names = separateNames($row->firstName);

  $connection->query('UPDATE contacts SET first_name="'.$names[0].'", last_name="'.$names[1].'" WHERE id='.$row->id);
}

$statement->free_result();
$statement->close();

$connection->close();
```

Can I use the `$connection->query` while having the statement open?

Best regards.

**UPDATE**

The `$connection->query(...)` returns `FALSE` and I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'MySQL Error - 2014 : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'
```

I changed the code to the following and worked:

```
$connection = new mysqli(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_PORT);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, first_name FROM contacts");

while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
  $names = separateNames($row[1]);

  $connection->query('UPDATE contacts SET first_name="'.$names[0].'", last_name="'.$names[1].'" WHERE id='.$row[0]);
}

$connection->close();
```

Comment: Please show separateNames function.

Comment: Divide your problem: You either have a problem to split the string or to create a SQL query. Ask specifically. Also [make use of prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: "but for some reason it isn't doing what I wanted": means what?

Comment: @hakre: My problem was never to separate the strings. My problem is that the update query is not being executed.

Comment: @viakondratiuk: the separateNames function returns an array with two elements: the first name and the last name. If you want I can post the function, but that's not my issue.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: Then check the return value, and if it is `FALSE` then  output the mysql error to learn more what you did wrong. I still keep my suggestion that you should (must!) do prepared statements instead of `query()` to properly encode the update values. If you don't want to prepare you will need to encode the values your own so that a valid SQL query is ensured. Right now you are blindly creating the SQL query which might cause your error. Also assign the SQL query to a variable first so that you can output it and verify it your own. Improve your trouble-shooting.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: Either answer your own question (and accept your answer then) or accept an existing one. But do not edit the question to place the answer there. I've taken your update down into my answer, feel free to add your own answer instead, I will remove it later then. Just ping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only have one active statement at a given time, so I had to make one of the queries via the `$connection->query()` method.

As @hakre mentioned:

> I still keep my suggestion that you should (must!) do prepared statements instead of query() to properly encode the update values

I opted to use the statement method for the update query, so the final working code is the following:

```
$connection = new mysqli(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_PORT);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, first_name FROM contacts");

$statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE contacts SET first_name=?, last_name=? WHERE id=?");

while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
  $names = separateNames($row[1]);

  $statement->bind_param('ssi', $names[0], $names[1], $row[0]);
  throwExceptionOnMySQLStatementError($statement, "Could not bind parameters", $logger);

  $statement->execute();
  throwExceptionOnMySQLStatementError($statement, "Could not execute", $logger);
}

$statement->free_result();
$statement->close();

$connection->close();
```

Thanks to all that gave their inputs, specially to @hakre that helped me to reach this final solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the `$connection->query` while having the statement open?

Yes. It will return a new result object or just a boolean depending on the SQL query, see http://php.net/mysqli_query - In your case of running an `UPDATE` query it will always return a boolean, `FALSE` if it failed, `TRUE` if it worked.

BTW, the [Mysqli connection object](http://php.net/class.mysqli) is not the [Mysqli statement object](http://php.net/class.mysqli-stmt), so they normally do not interfere with each other (disconnecting might destroy/break some statements under circumstances, but I would consider this an edge-case for your question you can ignore for the moment).

I wonder why you ask actually. Maybe you should improve the way you do trouble-shooting?

Comment: The query method either returns a boolean value or a mysqli_result object (http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), not a new statement object.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: What is the concrete SQL query literally? What is the return value of the `->query()` operation? What are [the reported errors of the `$connection` object](http://php.net/mysqli.error-list)? Please provide all these three and I will tell you more. -- Ask the right question and you will get the right answer ;)

Comment: **The concrete query:** UPDATE contacts SET first_name="Helio", last_name="Moryso" WHERE id=5

**The return value:** bool(false)

**Error:** PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'MySQL Error - 2014 : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'

Comment: BTW, I know the connection is not the statement... and my question is the right one: "Can I use the $connection->query while having the statement open?". Apparently not.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: You still can call that query, what is missing is your error checking. And the statement is less the problem, you've got the result open. Free the result first and you *can* `$connection->query` *successfully* while having the statement "open". Also don't speak so clever now, you didn't do any trouble-shooting, and wouldn't I have commented this way, you would have never seen this error message. So just start to tidy up now instead of complaining that you got some help. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: If I free the result before calling the $connection->query I won't be able to loop over all the other rows, so the while loop will become useless. Your solution is of no use.
"you would have never seen this error message" -> How do you know? Just because I cleaned the code I pasted here for the sake of readability it doesn't mean that I don't have any error checking methods implemented.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: Sure I don't know. However, when somebody asks a question here, it's common to put the error messages into the question. If you did recieve the error message earlier and you didn't put it in, it's your fault anyway. Next time, add your error message, you will get answers much faster. Also what you experience here can be related to client library versions and server configuration. E.g. if you can't have more than one statement active, write your code that way. Also I did not wanted to rob your "answer", please add it your own if my answer was not helpful to you.

Comment: Ok, you're right about putting the error message in advance, my fault. But still your tone was slightly inappropriate and I didn't like the fact that you deleted MY code from the question to put it on YOUR answer. Don't take me wrong, I appreciate a lot the fact that you're taking your time to answer me and trying to help, but if you can point out the fact that I didn't give all the info initially I can point out the things mentioned above. So we can take these and start to escalate the tone or we can simply recognize we started on the wrong foot and try to have a sane discussion.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: That is why I *commented* that upfront and I wrote, copy the code from your question (history is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14358748/revisions) and **add it as an answer** - Do not put your answer into your question. That is the only point I'm concerned about. I remove it from my answer now, but if you don't add your answer, I will put it back. Just saying.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that comment. Also didn't read the comment above that made me alter the solution. I'll send you the final code for you to post as answer since it was based on your comment.

Comment: @JorgeRaimundo: Please answer the question your own, I won't be able to check my emails for some days now. This is perfectly fine btw.